# Delete getters/setters Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I had created a getter/setter in $scope variable of angularjs

```
  Object.defineProperty($scope,
      "isActive", {
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true,
        get: function get() {
          return $scope.controlStatus;
        },
        set: function set(val) {
          $scope.controlStatus = val;
          _.isFunction($scope.callback) ? $scope.callback({ id: $scope.for, status: val }) : null;
        } });
```

i want to delete this getter/setter in particular condition, please suggest me how should i do it ??

Comment: Did you try to reset define it do default descriptor? As your prop is configurable everything should be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the condition is external you can always set both the getter and setter to undefined after the fact:

```
Object.defineProperty($scope,
  "isActive", {
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true,
    get: undefined,
    set: undefined
  }
);
```

As an alternative, you could stringify + parse the object back into the property, e.g.:

```
$scope.isActive = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.isActive));
```

Comment: That is quite odd... You can always just stringify and parse the object back as a new one as an alternative.

Comment: well my bad i was assigning null  , but we have to specific use 'undefined' only :)